# 1st day of month to previous Saturday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to filter data to only include the first day of the month until the previous saturday. For example, if I ran the query on 6-14-19(Friday) then the data will only include from 6-1-19 to 6-8-19(Saturday).

Right now I only have a month-to-date filter:

```
@SampleDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEADD(day, 0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

I would like to know how to get previous Saturday's date using GETDATE() so I can replace the upper limit of my current month-to-date filter.

Edit: I just realized about the special cases. If the previous week's Saturday is in a previous month then I would like to be able to get last month's dates instead. For example, If I ran this query on 5-1-19(Wednesday), then I would like the data from 4-1-19 to 4-27-19(Saturday). Another issue is if the current day is Saturday, if today is currently a Saturday then I will still need the previous' Saturday's date and not today's date.

Comment: To get the previous Saturday, you can use `SELECT DATEADD(Day, -(Datepart(Weekday, GetDate())), Cast(Getdate() as Date))`. Note, however, that you need a separate check to see if this runs past the first of the month. For example, if you run this against the date '2019-05-03' (May 3rd, 2019), it returns an answer of 2019-04-27 (April 27th). You also need to specify how you handle running this on Saturday, just in case - if run on Saturday, should it subtract 0 or 7 from the current date?

Comment: To subtract zero when run on Saturday, you can change this to:  `SELECT DATEADD(Day, -((Datepart(Weekday, GetDate())%7)), Cast(Getdate() as Date))`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this-

```
DECLARE @RunDate DATE = '20190617'

SELECT 
CASE WHEN A.StartDate > A.EndDate THEN DATEADD(MM,-1, A.StartDate) ELSE A.StartDate END StartDate,  
A.EndDate 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(DD,-(DATEPART(DD,@RunDate))+1,@RunDate) AS DATE) AS StartDate,
    CASE DATENAME(weekday,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-0,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-1,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Monday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-2,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-3,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-4,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Thursday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-5,@RunDate)
        WHEN 'Friday' THEN DATEADD(DD,-6,@RunDate)
    END AS EndDate
) A
```

Comment: I just realized about the special cases. If the previous week's Saturday is in a previous month then I would like to be able to get last month's dates instead. For example, If I ran this query on 5-1-19(Wednesday), then I would like the data from 4-1-19 to 4-27-19(Saturday). Another issue is if the current day is Saturday, if today is currently a Saturday then I will still need the previous' Saturday's date and not today's date.

Comment: @ReportWriter, changed a bit. It should work for your late realized scenario as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query.

```
declare @date datetime = getdate() --Todays date
select <Column1>,
    <Column2>,
    .........
    from <YourTableName>
where <YourDateColumn> between
    datefromparts(Year(@date), Month(@date), 1) -- First date of month
    and
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 5, @date) /7 * 7, 5) --Previous Saturday
```

You can check with the below implementation.

```
create table TableA(
    Name Varchar(50),
    DOJ Date
    )

Insert into TableA Values 
 ('A', '2019-06-01'), 
 ('B', '2019-06-02'),
 ('C', '2019-06-03'), 
 ('D', '2019-06-04'), 
 ('E', '2019-06-05'),
 ('F', '2019-06-15'), 
 ('G', '2019-06-06'), 
 ('H', '2019-06-08'), 
 ('I', '2019-06-09')

declare @date datetime = getdate() --Todays date
select 
    *
    from TableA
where DOJ between
    datefromparts(Year(@date), Month(@date), 1) -- First date of month
    and
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 5, @date) /7 * 7, 5) --Previous Saturday
```

The output is as shown below.

```
Name    DOJ
-----------------------
A   01.06.2019 00:00:00
B   02.06.2019 00:00:00
C   03.06.2019 00:00:00
D   04.06.2019 00:00:00
E   05.06.2019 00:00:00
G   06.06.2019 00:00:00
H   08.06.2019 00:00:00
```

If you are running your query on `Saturday` it self then to get the previous `Saturday` you can subtract one day from the execution date.

```
declare @date datetime = '2019-06-15' --Todays date
if (DATENAME(weekday,@date))='Saturday'
begin
    set @date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @date)
end
```

And you can see the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/GDVCJ51755).

Comment: I just realized about the special cases. If the previous week's Saturday is in a previous month then I would like to be able to get last month's dates instead. For example, If I ran this query on 5-1-19(Wednesday), then I would like the data from 4-1-19 to 4-27-19(Saturday). Another issue is if the current day is Saturday, if today is currently a Saturday then I will still need the previous' Saturday's date and not today's date.

Comment: @ReportWriter it is giving the output as per your statement kindly check.

Comment: @ReportWriter For verification of your statement please look into the link https://rextester.com/XPTX3609